# Swift 5 - Facebook Login: LoginManager() callback doesn't call with Facebook App installed

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I've updated Facebook SDK to the latest version with cocoapods:

- Using FBSDKCoreKit (5.8.0)
- Using FBSDKLoginKit (5.8.0)
- Using FacebookCore (0.9.0)
- Using FacebookLogin (0.9.0)

When Facebook app is installed, `LoginManager()` callback is not called. When the app is not installed and the browser is used, it works.

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self, completion: { loginResult in
    switch loginResult {
    case .failed(let error):
        print("\(error)")
    case .cancelled:
        print("cancelled")
    case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
        print("\(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions)")
    }
})
```

Any idea?

Comment: Same here. Any luck?

Comment: @ShakeebAhmad You have to use the new SDK, check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating to the new SDK solved:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit/Swift'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit/Swift'
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. For me it was missing code from the AppDelegate (we don't use a SceneDelegate). The sign in would work unless the FB app was installed. The former used a web view type UI but the latter switched to the FB app, then when returned to our app it hang. Looking at the FB account I could see the sign in had worked successfully.

Check the FB docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/

(5. Connect Your App Delegate and Scene Delegate)

Comment: FB docs is socks, there is no clear document to making custom login button in Swift.